# How set point type from data in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, points

How set point type from data in gnuplot?

gnuplot script:

```
set terminal pngcairo size 640,480
set output "points.png" 
set style data points 
set auto x 
set autoscale x 
unset colorbox 
plot 'test.data' using 2:1 with points notitle
```

test.data

```
32  35  8
34  34  6
36  28  1
34  32  2
28  30  7
38  30  9
34  29  2
35  36  9
39  34  3
31  33  9
28  31  6
35  30  5
33  41  4
32  37  3
```

how get point type from 3 column?

```
plot 'gnuplot.data' using 2:1 with points pt (:3) notitle // error
```

abstraction example:

[image]

need:

[image]

*gnuplot Version 4.6 patchlevel 4*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no option to select the point type from the data file based on a column (equivalent to `linecolor variable`, `pointsize variable` or `arrowstyle variable`). Basically you have two options:

1. Iterate over all possible point types (which you can extract with `stats` if this should be variable) and for each number plot only those points which match the current point type:

   ```
   stats 'test.data' using 3 nooutput
   unset key
   set style data points
   plot for [i=STATS_min:STATS_max] 'test.data' using 2:($3 == i ? $1 : 1/0) lt 1 pt i ps 2
   ```

[image]

2. Use the `labels` plotting style and a sequence of unicode point symbols from which you select using the value from the third column as index. (use e.g. http://www.shapecatcher.com or http://decodeunicode.org/en/geometric_shapes to find suitable symbols)

   ```
   unset key
   set encoding utf8
   symbol(z) = "•✷+△♠□♣♥♦"[int(z):int(z)]
   plot 'test.data' using 2:1:(symbol($3)) with labels textcolor lt 1
   ```

[image]